# Jenkins job disables itself when svn checkout fails

Tags: jenkins, svn, jobs, svn-checkout

My jenkins jobs started to disable by themselves when the svn checkout fails. I explored previous builds and they never disabled when failed. This new behaviour is not desired for me.

The message in the new build log is as follows:

```
...
One or more repository locations do not exist anymore for myJob1, project will be disabled.
The project has been disabled
ERROR: Failed to parse svn info for 'repourl'
...
```

I downgraded the jenkins Subversion plugin which was recently updated, and the multi scm plugin as well. However, the problem remains.
Any suggestion?

Comment: This issue is related (https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24341), it is resolved. Also, in this class [SubversionSCM.java](https://github.com/jenkinsci/subversion-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/scm/SubversionSCM.java) disabling is implemented, after 10 builds where checkout failed. It have sense, since my jobs have failed 10 times aproximately. But, where to check the project MakeDisabled or not?

Answer (score 2):

That message is coming from the [Blame Subversion Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/BlameSubversion-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/hudson/scm/subversion/Messages.properties). Is it possible you recently installed that plugin? Or that you recently turned on SVN blame as an option?

Comment: I do not have the Blame Subversion Plugin installed. Following your tip, I made a similar search in github and I found the same text message in the code of the [Subversion Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/subversion-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/hudson/scm/subversion/Messages.properties), so the problem comes from Subversion Plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an undocumented(?) behavior of the [Subversion Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin) to automatically disable a job if the SVN URL is not valid (anymore). This behavior seems to be implemented for several years now, as [this discussion from 2012](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/anonymous-disables-jobs-td4417803.html) indicates. I just learned about this behavior only after moving a SVN project to a different folder which caused my project to be disabled. I did not find any information on how to disable this behavior.

###### Update 2021/09:

The behavior is apparently still present and there seems to be no way to disable it.
There is a corresponding feature request on the Jenkins JIRA though: [JENKINS-10922](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-10922)

Please vote for this feature request!

Comment: I have Jenkins ver. 2.190.3 and latest subversion plugin 2.13.1 and the problem is still there! I have Pool SCM option on with: H/2 * * * *. And if i enable job it will get disabled within 2 mintues. HOW TO REMOVE THIS FUNCTIONALITY? :((